# Looking for IMU simulation software

Tags: kalman-filter, imu

If I am posting this in the wrong place, please let me know (I'll move the question there).

I am looking for a program that can generate 6 or 9 DoF `IMU` data along with its actual path.

I am working on implementing **`Kalman`** filter and require data. The requirement is that there is a camera **`C`** and object **`X`**. **`X`** and **`C`** both have `IMU` attached to it and both can move freely. The camera has a function that can extract the `3D` position of **`X`**.

I need a simulator that can simulate this scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: Yup not the best place to ask that type of question. As for the answer, I've recently come across the V-REP simulator (http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/downloads.html) which I think can just do what you want. You can download and use the executables/libs freely, but I'm not sure about the licence.

Comment: wow.. that software looks amazing... Blows my mind how people are able to create it..